# SQL. Количество записей в связанной таблице

Tags: sql

Очень простой для многих вопрос:

Есть таблица `category` (`id`, `name`)
И связанная таблица неких сущностей `entity` (`id`, `category_id`, `name`)

Необходимо вытащить все категории и количество сущностей в каждой. Написал

```
select * from category left join entity on category.id = entity.id
```

А дальше тупик.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
  c.*,
  count(e.id)
from category c
left join entity e
  on c.id = e.category_id
group by c.id;
```

Comment: ОШИБКА: столбец "c.name" должен фигурировать в предложении GROUP BY или использоваться в агрегатной функции

Comment: Можно обойти, чтоб все поля не перечислять? Их там много на самом деле

Comment: Если в выводе их все надо получить, то нельзя обойти.

Comment: Спасибо. Значит так и буду делать

Comment: Во-первых, запрос в ответе не рабочий, по указанной ТС причине, во-вторых, это таки можно обойти, еслив запросе написать select c.id, count(e.id) .... и сделать этот запрос подзапросом для таблички категорий со связкой по c.id

Comment: @NickProskuryakov http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcbe77/1

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev SSMS этот запрос не пропускает.

Comment: если выбрать MySQL 5.6 то работает